# Using OkHttp library for posting to a PHP script that saves to MySQL from Android Application

Tags: android, okhttp

Im trying to make a post request using okhttp in android. Im facing a challenge where the data is not posting to the server and im failing to see the reason why. I am using the mysql database on my local machine

Here is the code from the android application

Using OkHttp library for posting to a PHP script that saves to MySQL. Im trying to log the error to the console but nothing is displaying

```
btnSaveNotes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String gotSpeakerName = speakerName.getText().toString();
                String gotSpeakerDate = sermonDate.getText().toString();
                String gotenNotes = notes.getText().toString();

                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("speaker", gotSpeakerName)
                        .add("date", gotSpeakerDate)
                        .add("notes",gotenNotes)
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://10.0.2.2/notes/addOneNote.php").post(formBody).build();
                Call call = client.newCall(request);

                call.enqueue(new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Registration Error" + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                    }

                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                        //  Log.e(TAG_REGISTER, "Registration error: " + e.getMessage());
                        System.out.println("Post Error to the Server" + e.getMessage());
                    }


                    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                        try {

                            String resp = response.body().string();
                            System.out.println(resp);

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {


                            } else {

                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Log.e(TAG_REGISTER, "Exception caught: ", e);
                            System.out.println("Exception caught" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is the php script that is responsible for sending the data to the mysql database

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
//class that will post the notes to the database
class addOneNote{

    public $connection;
    public $connectionFunction;

    //constructor function that will initialize the connection and connect to the database
    public function __construct(){

        $this->connection = new DbConn();
        $this->connectionFunction = $this->connection->connect();
    }

    //function that will add the a single note to the database.......
    public function addSingleNote($speaker,$date,$notes){
        
        $statement = $this->connectionFunction->prepare("insert into notes(speaker,date,notes)values(:speaker,:date,:notes)");
        $statement->bindParam(":speaker",$speaker);
        $statement->bindParam(":date",$date);
        $statement->bindParam(":notes",$notes);

        $result = $statement->execute();
       
        if($result){


            $response  = array();
            $response["code"] = 1;
            $response["status"] = "inserted";
            
            echo json_encode($response);


        }else{


            $response = array();
            $response["code"] = 0;
            $response["status"] = "not inserted";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        
    }
}


//object of a single note initialized
$speaker = $_POST["speaker"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$notes = $_POST["notes"];
$notes = new addOneNote();
//$notes->addNote("itai chiriseri","7 July 2021","this is my first note. Testing....");
$notes->addSingleNote($speaker,$date,$notes);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

From PHP you returning always some response like inserted and not inserted so if record not inserted then it will return not inserted response not some exception.

If you would like to get any exceptions then from PHP give some wrong database connection values then you will get Connection refused exception.